# How to connect my nodeApp with another NodeApp running on Docker?

Tags: docker, nodes

I have two NodeJS container that I would like to connect.

the first works as an API which returns json file,

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');

// Form data
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({
  extended: true
}))

// set port port=4444 node app.js
var port = process.env.PORT || 3001;

//ROUTES FOR API
//get the router instance from express
var router = express.Router();

//test route on accessed at GET http://localhost:8080/api
router.get('/', function(req, res) {
  res.json({message:'hello Welcome to our api'});
});

//all of our routes will be prfixed with /api
app.use('/api', router);

// server start
app.listen(port);
console.log('The server is running on localhost:' + port);
```

and the second (my webservice) make a request to this API to make GET POST method later.

```
var http = require("http");
var request = require('request');
var express = require('express');
var app = express();



    request({ url: "nodeapi:/loving_mccarthy:3001/api",
                    method: "GET",
                    headers: { "Content-Type": "application/json" },
                    json: true,

                }, function (error, response, body) {
                  if(error) {
                    console.log(error);
                  } else {
                    console.log(response.statusCode);
                    console.log('the api contents: \n' + body.message);
                  }
                  });
```

I already have the second container linked to the first so (`docker run -d --link nodeapi:nodeapi -v /vagrant_workspace/nodejs_test/src:/usr/src/app/src eddy/node_test:v3` ).

but I don't know how I can write the code in the second, so that the url and a argument comming from the first container is called in the second.

Answer (score 0):

[Links are a legacy feature](https://docs.docker.com/engine/userguide/networking/default_network/dockerlinks/) - the preferred way to do this now is with [Docker networks](https://docs.docker.com/engine/userguide/networking/).

You create a network first, and when you run containers in the same network they can access each other by DNS, using the name of the container:

```
> docker network create my-app
aeb906ae13daf10331fefa026621fd11d9e6a8112757308cda82ad969a1cea6b    

> docker run -d --name api --network my-app nginx:alpine
68ed7384891fcc6563d6dfe740fb2f09f058b308c333c73b47f511b2fed5cf6f

> docker run -d --name web --network my-app nginx:alpine
eecbefd788383553d4fb1429ef207b5b83d57165ce39db0d100da318dadef541
```

Simple example with `ping`:

```
> docker exec web ping -c 1 api
PING api (172.19.0.2): 56 data bytes
64 bytes from 172.19.0.2: seq=0 ttl=64 time=0.091 ms                                                                                                        

> docker exec api ping -c 1 web
PING web (172.19.0.3): 56 data bytes
64 bytes from 172.19.0.3: seq=0 ttl=64 time=0.107 ms
```

In your code, you refer to the services by their DNS name (e.g. web, api, db) and let Docker deal with the discovery.

Answer (score 0):

hi Elton and first thank you for the Answer but,
when I try to work with docker network, it isn't workink i become this:

```
$ docker network
docker: 'network' is not a docker command. See 'docker --help'.
```

However i can too ping the nodeapi container form the web:

```
root@fbfd0f8fa01d:/usr/src/app/src# ping nodeapi
PING nodeapi (172.17.0.1): 56 data bytes
64 bytes from 172.17.0.1: icmp_seq=0 ttl=64 time=0.283 ms
```

but if try do request to the node api inside web like:

```
request({ url: "nodeapi:/<web_container_name>:3001/api",
                    method: "GET",
                    headers: { "Content-Type": "application/json" },
                    json: true,

                }, function (error, response, body) {
                  if(error) {
                    console.log(error);
                  } else {
                    console.log(response.statusCode);
                    console.log('the api contents: \n' + body.message);
                  }
                  });
```

or like:

```
request({ url: "http://172.17.0.1:3001/api",
                    method: "GET",
                    headers: { "Content-Type": "application/json" },
                    json: true,

                }, function (error, response, body) {
                  if(error) {
                    console.log(error);
                  } else {
                    console.log(response.statusCode);
                    console.log('the api contents: \n' + body.message);
                  }
                  });
```

The request does'nt work.

Hier you can see the Container ENV

```
root@fbfd0f8fa01d:/usr/src/app/src# env | grep NODEAPI
NODEAPI_PORT_3001_TCP_ADDR=172.17.0.1
NODEAPI_ENV_http_proxy=http://10.0.2.2:3128
NODEAPI_PORT_3001_TCP_PORT=3001
NODEAPI_PORT_3001_TCP_PROTO=tcp
NODEAPI_PORT=tcp://172.17.0.1:3001
NODEAPI_ENV_NPM_CONFIG_LOGLEVEL=info
NODEAPI_NAME=/loving_carson/nodeapi
NODEAPI_ENV_NODE_VERSION=4.5.0
NODEAPI_ENV_https_proxy=http://10.0.2.2:3128
NODEAPI_PORT_3001_TCP=tcp://172.17.0.1:3001
root@fbfd0f8fa01d:/usr/src/app/src#
```

Comment: What `docker version` are you running?